# Large family of subsets of odd size such that the pairwise intersections also have odd size

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to prove that for some $\alpha > 1$ and every $n ≥ 5$, there is a family $F ⊂ P(n)$ of size at least $\alpha^{n}$ such that every set in $F$ has odd size, and the
intersection of any two distinct sets from $F$ has odd size.

I'm aware that this is a variation of the Oddtown theorem, but can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2.$

Given $n\ge5,$ let $k=\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor,$ let $n\supseteq\{0\}\cup P_1\cup P_2\cup\cdots\cup P_k$ where $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_k$ are disjoint two-element sets not containing $0,$ and let $F$ be the family consisting of all sets of the form $\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{i\in I}P_i$ where $I\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,k\}.$

Then $|F|=2^k=2^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\ge2^{n/3}=\alpha^n.$